# ASP.NET Core, Angular SPA app check if the first time page loaded

Tags: angular

How can I check in `ts` file, if it's the first time that the page is loaded, something like `if (!IsPostBack)`, all the answers that i am finding for that subject, are for `asp.net` 
to set cliectScript parmater into client page..

how can it be done in ASP.core Angular SPA application

What i want to achieve is something like this:

### app.ts

```
...
if(!IsPostBack){
   // the first time the page has loaded
}
...
```

Comment: in SPA, How can you expect the page load? Because Angular provide this as a feature for not refresh the screen while navigating.

Comment: i believe that the right way it can be achieved is by setting it via server code. but i didn't find how...

Comment: you are thinking about this the wrong way.  In Angular, the first time the page loads is when the Angular app is first loaded.  Angular then will not reload the page, thus there will never be a PostBack to the server.   Angular provides hooks for when the app is loaded as well as for when a component is loaded, and you should use those.

Comment: The entry component is app component.

Comment: @Claies, so how can i find, if the component is loaded for the first time? (not the whole app)

Comment: this should give you a good idea where to start: 
 https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/lifecycle-hooks/